# How to not SELECT rows that contain NULL entries, or fill the NULL with 0 or NA, in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, null

I use SQLite with R to store data that are too large for RAM. This allows me to SELECT and JOIN outside of RAM. My data are in general well-groomed, but sometimes there are null entries and I have no prior on where these null entries might be (nor do I care, I am happy to omit those rows).

Is there a way that I can not SELECT or return rows with null entries without specifically testing each column? Or replace all null entries with 0 or NA? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can not SELECT or return rows with null entries without specifically testing each column?

To do this you need to test every column to see if it is NULL.

However if you don't like writing `WHERE col1 IS NOT NULL AND col2 IS NOT NULL AND ...` then you could try using [`coalesce`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) or if all your columns have the same type you could try `max`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM yourtable
WHERE max(col1, col2, col3) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the education. This helps!

Comment: @richards, Sorry, but my `coalesce` example ignored rows where *all* values were null. If you want to ignore rows where *any* value is null then I think `max` might be able to help you.

Comment: Thanks. You had my case right, though. I just want to avoid occasional and sporadic nulls.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `COALESCE` function:

```
SELECT COALESCE(myColumn, 'valueIfNull')
FROM Table
```